# Send message using websockets with another thread without RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketCommonProtocol.send' was never awaited

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

Am trying to send motion sensor data in json string using websocket client in another thread to avoid execution blocking for the rest of the code down by an infinite loop in MotionSensor class. but apparently the `ws.send()` needs await keyword. And if i add it throught i get an error

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MotionSensors.run' was never awaited
self.run()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
and it doesn't send anything to the server

```
# motionSensor.py
import threading
import time
from client.ClientRequest import Request


class MotionSensors(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ws):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ws = ws
        self.open = True

    async def run(self):
        await self.SendData()

    async def SendData(self):
        while self.open:
            print("Sending motion state....")
            state = 1 # Motion state demo value
            request = Request()
            request.push("mcu/sensors/motion")
            request.addBody({
                "state_type": "single",
                "devices": {"state": state, "device_no": "DVC-876435"}
            })
            await self.ws.send(request.getAsJsonString())
            print("sleeping now for 2 seconds....")
            time.sleep(2)
```

here is my main code
client.py

```
# client.py
import settings
import asyncio
import websockets
from client.ClientHandler import Devices
from client.Rounte import Route
from ClientRequest import Request
from client.dbHandler import mcuConfig
from client.devices.motionSensor import MotionSensors

def ResponseMSG(request):
    print(request)

route = Route()
route.addRoute("/response", ResponseMSG)


def onMessage(request):
    route.fireRequest(request)

async def WsClient():
    uri = settings.WS_URL
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        #####################################
        ###INITIALIZE DEVICES
        motion = MotionSensors(websocket)
        motion.start()
        while True:
            print("waiting to recieve......")
            message = await websocket.recv()
            onMessage(message)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(WsClient())
loop.run_forever()
```

Guys i need your help to send data in another thread with a while loop without blocking the execution of code down and without errors. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Err, `await` it?

Comment: No the error is raised from motionSensor class where i add async on each function including run and  there is no way to await the run function , i start the thread using the  start() function

Comment: You cannot define `run` as async because the contract of `threading.Thread` mandates that it be sync. You need to define `run` with `def run(self)` and call `loop.run_until_complete(self.SendData())`. (You might need to first create an event loop with `asyncio.new_event_loop()` and set it for the current thread with `asyncio.set_event_loop()`.) But the question is why do you use threads in the first place? If both the websockets code and the motion sensors code are async, you can just call `asyncio.create_task(MotionSensors().SendData())` and not bother with any of the thread stuff.

Comment: user4815162342 it actually  worked, I used your last advice of creating a new task with this code asyncio.create_task(MotionSensors().SendData()) . Thank you very much

Comment: @user4815162342  hi, i have tried to send data back to client from server, but it is not recieved its seems the loop is executed once. i used the  **asyncio.create_task(MotionSensors().SendData()) **

Comment: @kikabifrancis You can add debugging prints to find out _why_ the loop only gets executed once - it could be because of an exception or a logic error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i changed the code of motionSensor.py
i created a new event loop and i set it to the new thread
and it worked for the case of even those using python 3.7 and below. it works. All thanks to @user4815162342

```
# motionSensor.py

import threading
import time
import asyncio
from client.ClientRequest import Request

class MotionSensor(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, ws):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    self.ws = ws
    self.open = True

def run(self):
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.SendData())

# @asyncio.coroutine
async def SendData(self):
    while True:
        print("Sending motion state....")
        state = 0
        request = Request()
        request.push("mcu/sensors/motion")
        request.addBody({
            "state_type": "single",
            "devices": {"state": state, "device_no": "DVC-876435"}
        })
        await self.ws.send(request.getAsJsonString())
        print("sleeping now for 5 seconds....")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This code looks wrong because it uses `time.sleep()` in an asyncio coroutine, which will block the event loop. Starting two event loops from two different threads is a very advanced use of asyncio which should not be attempted unless you have a good reason and you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I tried using asyncio.create_task(MotionSensors().SendData()) but I wasn't receiving data from the server, I could only send and seem the code was executing up to the receive loop but no data was being received, let me try again because I changed some code on my websocket server